# Применить стиль исходя из размера строки в div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой div который выводит пары ключ:значение. И может быть так, что значение больше условно 100 знаков. Тогда нужно писать "..." вместо продолжения строки.

```
<div class="style">
  <div *ngFor="let variable of variableValues; trackBy: variableTrackBy" class="style-item">
    <div *ngIf="!isMobileView" class="knf-variable-wrapper">
      {{variable.label}}:&nbsp;{{getFormattedValue(variable)}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

можете подсказать куда нужно прописать js скрипт который бы делал подсчет символов и как потом вызвать нужный стиль который бы применялся к значению превышаемую 100 знаков.

я попробовал написать такой js но он не работает и я не очень понимаю как его вызвать из html

```
 public showEllipsis(subject: string): boolean {
    if (subject) {
      const initialLenghtOfSubject: number = subject.length;

      return initialLenghtOfSubject > 100;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: может просто css-свойство `text-overflow: ellipsis;` подойдет?

Comment: нет к сожалению т.к. оно не учитывает условие с ограничением длинны строки

Comment: `newStr = str.length > 100 ? str.substr(0, 97) + '...' : str;`

Comment: Так у вас это angular. Вызовите на шаблоне вот так `{{variable.label?.length > 100 ? variable.label?.substr(0, 97) + '...' : variable.label}}`